# Blockchain Computation Encryption

Tags: encryption, blockchain, ethereum, computation

I have a sensitive data A (floating point) and nobody should be able to see the raw data.
A user submits some data B which is added to data A. Data B can be seen by anybody. The result of the computation is sent back to the user.
The computation should be done somewhere which could be permanent i.e. not on a private server.  Data could be stored in IPFS.
E.g. data A could be encrypted and stored in Ethereum somewhere where the data persists.I thought about pallier homomorphic encryption for the computation but it is too slow i.e. encrypt data A and data B and perform addition.

Any suggestions guys?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad, doesn't seem to have a significant programming component, is somewhat unclear, and is likely to draw long opinionated answers. To the extent that it is clear it would likely be a better fit on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please read [What questions can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)